# Do SELinux management commands operate on the kernel or the filesystem?

Tags: linux, selinux, kickstart, anaconda

We're installing RPMs into a CentOS 7 system using Anaconda + Kickstart, which does a `chroot` into the target system's environment and installs all of the RPMs we specify in our Kickstart config file. In some of these RPMs, the `%pre` or `%post` scriptlets are running the SELinux commands `semodule`, `semanage` and `restorecon` to set up our needed SELinux policy.

When installing these RPMs normally (i.e. in an already-installed system), the scriptlets are executing as expected and setting up the SELinux policy on the system. But when we install these RPMs via Anaconda, the commands are succeeding, but none of the SELinux policy actually takes effect in the installed system upon a reboot: none of the modules installed via `semodule` are installed, and none of the context mappings configured via `semanage` are in place.

For example, we have a module `mymodule.pp` which we install in our `%post` script via `semodule -i mymodule.pp` and a file context mapping definition that we set as `semanage fcontext -a -t mysqld_db_t '/storage/export(/.*)?'`; these commands "succeed" during the Anaconda install, but upon rebooting into the actual system, none of the policies are in place.

---

So this brings my question: when I manage my system's SELinux policy using e.g. `semodule`, `semanage` and `restorecon`, are these commands managing the *currently running kernel*? Is that why they're not being seen in the newly-installed system? Or might I have something else going on here? I would have figured that running these commands would put/changed a file in the filesystem that would get read by the (newly-installed) kernel on boot to set the policy and contexts.

Comment: These commands generally operate on the SELinux configuration in `/etc/selinux` and then tell the kernel to reload it once they're done. You should pull the installation log from one of these systems before it reboots out of Anaconda and take a look at it.

Comment: @MichaelHampton so I think one part of my question is actually wrong: the commands don't "succeed" in Anaconda. So maybe I should edit. I'm getting this error message upon running `semodule -i <module>`: `Failed to resolve typeattributeset statement at /etc/selinux/targeted/tmp/modules/400/httpd_mysqld_db/cil:1` and then `/usr/sbin/semodule: Failed!` So that was an oversight on my part in the OP. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you use the name of a policy that already exists? If so, see https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3492361

Comment: @MichaelHampton No, this is a unique policy name (`httpd_mysql_db`). It might be worth noting that I compiled this SELinux module on a development CentOS 7 machine (using `make -f /usr/share/selinux/devel/Makefile` on my `httpd_mysql_db.te` file) and then am trying to install that compiled module in Anaconda...admittedly, I don't know enough about compiling SELinux modules to know if that's okay.

Comment: That seems reasonable, except... Do you even need the policy module at all?

Comment: @MichaelHampton that's a good question for this particular case, but upon further research after posting this question, we have much larger SELinux issues with Kickstart as well. We also install Nginx and MariaDB, both of whose RPMs set SELinux policy as a `%post`-install scriptlet, and none of those are working when installed in the Kickstart environment either.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, Michael Hampton [was correct](https://serverfault.com/questions/957261/do-selinux-management-commands-operate-on-the-kernel-or-the-filesystem#comment1245262_957261) in that the SELinux tools operate on the filesystem. We can't find the root cause for why the SELinux policy definitions/modules aren't installing during the Kickstart package installation, but we implemented a workaround:

In our Kickstart ISO, we still put all of these extra packages we need into the package repository, but rather than listing the packages in the `%packages` section of `ks.cfg`, we install them in the `%post` section, e.g.:

```
additional_pkgs=(
MariaDB-10.3.13-centos73-x86_64-client.rpm
MariaDB-10.3.13-centos73-x86_64-server.rpm
MariaDB-10.3.13-centos73-x86_64-shared.rpm
galera-25.3.25-1.rhel7.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm
rh-nginx114-1.14-6.el7.x86_64.rpm
rh-nginx114-nginx-1.14.1-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
rh-nginx114-runtime-1.14-6.el7.x86_64.rpm
)
for ((i=0; i < "${#additional_pkgs[@]}"; i++)); do
    additional_pkgs[i]="/mnt/install/repo/Packages/${additional_pkgs[i]}"
done
rpm --root /mnt/sysimage --install "${additional_pkgs[@]}"
```

The unfortunate side effect is that we have to specify the full version number as opposed to just the package name, but we can probably implement a fairly straightforward solution to that when the need arises.

Now, with this workaround, our RPM packages' `%post` scriptlets that set SELinux policy definitions (or install modules) are working as expected.